# Use case diagram validation

Tags: uml, use-case

I would like to know if the following use case diagram is correct, and if it can be improved. The context is an e-learning application development.

[image]

The business rules are as follows:

1. All the actors can check the number of posts per person
2. Only the manager and the lecturer can check the density of words by group
3. Only the manager and the lecturer can check the density of words used in the contribution posts
4. All the actors can print the results
5. The developer develop the «Elaborate and design of number of posts function», the «Elaborate and design of words used in the contributions posts function» and the «Elaborate and design of words used in the contributions posts function» functions that respectively allow the user to check the the «number of posts per person», the «density of words by group» and the «density of words used in the contribution posts».
6. The actors must be logged.
7. The sub-independant software is the aplication where the empacked use cases takes place. So the login use case take place on the parent «Discussion forum».
8. The developer should be the left side of the use case diagram but given the lack of space I put it the right side of the picture. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Following observations:

- `Login` is not an use case at all. Remove it.
- `Sub-independent software` is not an actor as there is no use case for it. If there were some, the name would simply not mean anything (it could be the firmware of a tooth brush).
- The `Developer` UCs are by far too complex to be real use cases.
- `Display` and `Print` are no UCs. You seem to try to do functional decomposition here. This is wrong.
- `Computation` is not a use case at all.
- The connectors needs to be tidy. You can hardly see what is connected were.
- The `Check` UCs are hardly UCs. What value will that check bring?

I recommend to read Bittner/Spence or Cockburn. This one is, sorry to say, for the bin.